# Data Difference Between Where Clause and AND Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried these queries in our application. Each returned different result sets for me.

Query Set 1

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON (T1.ID = T2.ID
                              AND T1.STATUS = 'A'
                              AND T2.STATUS = 'A')
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON (T2.ID = T3.ID)
WHERE T3.STATUS = 'A'
```

Query Set 2

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON (T1.ID = T2.ID
                              AND T2.STATUS = 'A')
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON (T2.ID = T3.ID)
WHERE T3.STATUS = 'A'
  AND T1.STATUS  = 'A'
```

I couldn't find out why each query returns different outputs. Also please guide me about which approach is best when we use multiple `joins` (`left, right, Inner)` with `Filtering clauses.`

Thanks for any help

Comment: Any filtering with   a table column from the right of a LEFT JOIN will transform the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN The WHERE is executed after the JOIN filtering away results

Comment: I understood  that If we use Where clause in the right table of left out join, then it will become Inner join.  But what will happen if  inner join a 3rd table on the result set? does applying where clause on the 3rd table have any impact ?

Comment: where runs after join so yes it would keep only A's before join.

Comment: Your third table JOINs on diffrent results in this case,WHERE aside

Comment: @A.Greensmith Thats false WHERE run after JOINs

Comment: sorry you are correct, it would still change the result set and apply.

Comment: table 1 left join table 2 inner join table 3 . This query logic will give all table 1's data & common data with table 2 as Intermediate result.  this Intermediate result set then join with table 3 and give common data between table 3 & intermediate result set . Am I right on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON (T1.ID = T2.ID
                              AND T1.STATUS = 'A'
                              AND T2.STATUS = 'A')
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON (T2.ID = T3.ID)
WHERE T3.STATUS = 'A'
```

AND T1.STATUS = 'A' has zero effect
It is a left join - you are gong to get all of T1 period

When you move AND T1.STATUS = 'A' to the where then it is applied

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a filter on the right table of a left join, creating an inner join. Your first query will return less results, whilst your second will have NULLS against non matching rows on the right table. This link helped me to understand joins much better, as I really struggled for a long time to grasp the concept. [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)

If my answer is not clear please ask me for a revision.

Comment: Not that filter in the join does not create and inner join

Comment: What Will happen If I inner join a new table with left outer join result set and apply where clause on it?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in your code is the T1.STATUS = 'A' location.

Query 1:
You join the T1 and T2 tables on all the common IDS and only if both T1.STATUS = 'A' = T2.STATUS.

Query 2:
You join the T1 and T2 tables on all the common IDS and only if T2.STATUS = 'A'

Basically, query 1: you filter T1's data first and then you join.
query 2: you join the tables first and **then** you filter the data on the already joined table.

Also regarding the joins, usually the left and inner joins return the same results. Have a look [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/15/sql-server-interesting-observation-of-on-clause-on-left-join-how-on-clause-effects-resultset-in-left-join/) and [here](http://www.sql-join.com/) I found both links really useful.

Finally, my personal preference is to use inner joins unless I definitely need all the rows from either left or right table. I believe it makes my queries simpler to read and maintain.

I hope that helps.